# Read Java Heap Dump (.hprof file) using eclipse MAT api

Tags: java, heap-memory, profiler, mat

I am tying to read information about Java class , no of instance, it's size etc
from java heap dump.I was using Eclipse MAT jar files in my program to read the heap dump file.While running the program I am getting a NullPointerException.

**Below given is the code for accessing heap dump file**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SnapshotException {
        ISnapshot iSnapshot = SnapshotFactory.openSnapshot(new File("path to\\heap_dmp.hprof"), new VoidProgressListener());
        Collection<IClass> classes = iSnapshot.getClasses();
        System.out.println(" size = "+classes.size());
    }
```

While running the above program I am getting Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at heapanalyser.HeapAnalyser.main(HeapAnalyser.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.mat.snapshot.SnapshotFactory.<clinit>(SnapshotFactory.java:84)
    ... 1 more
```

Can anyone explain how to programatically analyse Heap Dumps

Comment: I have checked out the eclipse mat source code and it does heavily depends on eclipse platform. and the reason of your NPE is because the eclipse mat is trying to get the extension registry for which exists on eclipse platform. I did something similar to this. but, it's not straight forward as i did it with jhat and then parse the result.

Comment: So how we can use this eclipse mat api in our program for getting information from java heap dump.Is there any other java api for parsing java heap dumps and getting all the information in the heap dump.

Comment: @user3859408 You can try : org-netbeans-lib-profiler (available in maven central)
https://cuprak.info/2018/11/12/exploring-java-heap-dumps/